# Running Wolfram Engine on Android (aarch64)

Tags: android, debian, wolfram-mathematica, arm64

I tried to follow the answer posted here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/239308/53728, where the version of Mathematica for Raspberry Pi (armhf) was installed on Android phone.

But still I am getting the error

```
kirill@localhost:~$ wolfram ERROR: ld.so: object '/support/libdisableselinux.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored. /opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/12.3/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-ARM/WolframKernel: error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas.so.0: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied
```

tried to install open-blas libraries, but I think the problem isn't there

Such a pity: modern phone with 8 powerful cores, there is a free Wolfram Engine available, and I still can't utilize it's power in a proper way.

UPD:

Got managed to downgrade the Mathematica to 11.0 and manually install all libs, but now the error looks like

```
root@localhost:/opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/11.0/Executables# wolfram ERROR: ld.so: object '/support/libdisableselinux.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.  /opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/11.0/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-ARM/WolframKernel: error while loading shared libraries: /opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/11.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-ARM/libWolframEngine.so: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied
```

It looks like that I need somehow disable SELinux?

Comment: Got managed to downgrade the Mathematica to 11.0 and manually install all libs, but now the error looks odd
`
root@localhost:/opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/11.0/Executables# wolfram
ERROR: ld.so: object '/support/libdisableselinux.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
/opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/11.0/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-ARM/WolframKernel: error while loading shared libraries: /opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/11.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-ARM/libWolframEngine.so: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram recently released Mathematica for Raspberry PI, for ARM64. Finally, you can install it in termux just by executing script, provided [here](https://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/).

[This](https://wolfr.am/raspi-install) is direct link to script. It will download and install Wolfram engine and Mathematica for ARM64.
I managed to install it in termux, and even frontend (Mathematica) works just fine in VNC.